# ObjectDB, failed to write the value of field (error 363)

Tags: java, jpa, objectdb

I'm trying to make an application that can store a tree structure with files and folders in an ObjectDB database (embedde), but even with a simple test I keep getting an error...

### Entity classes

**Node.java**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Node {

    @Column(name = "Name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "Parent_FK")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FolderID", nullable = true)
    private FolderNode parent = null;

    public Node() {
    }

    public Node(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean hasParent() {
        return (parent != null);
    }

    public FolderNode getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    void setParent(FolderNode parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 31).append(name).toHashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj instanceof Label) { // TODO is instanceof enough??
            Label other = (Label) obj;
            return name.equals(other.getName());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**FolderNode.java**

```
@Entity(name = "Folders")
public class FolderNode extends Node {

    @Column(name = "FolderID")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Node> children = new HashSet<Node>();

    public FolderNode() {
    }

    public FolderNode(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public Set<Node> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(Set<Node> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

### Calling code

```
//Init
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("database.odb");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

//Create object
FolderNode rootFolder = new FolderNode("root");

//Persist
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(rootFolder);
em.getTransaction().commit();

em.close();
emf.close();

emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("database.odb");
em = emf.createEntityManager();

TypedQuery<FolderNode> query = em.createQuery("SELECT f FROM Folders f", FolderNode.class);
List<FolderNode> result = query.getResultList();
```

And that's where it crashes with an exception:

```
[ObjectDB 2.3.5_07] javax.persistence.PersistenceException
Failed to write the value of field field FolderNode.children using reflection (error 363)
```

The problem seems to go away if I don't close and reopen the EntityManagerFactory and EntityManager before fetching the object.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code demonstrates an issue in handling mapped super classes. If you replace the @MappedSuperclass annotation with @Entity (for the Node class) your test will work well.

ObjectDB should handle mapped super classes as entity classes, so following your post - this issue has been fixed and your test (with @MappedSuperclass) should work with build 2.3.6_14.

Comment: That code actually works for me too. BUT, if I close em and emf after the commit, and then repoen them using the same methods: emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("path/to/file.odb") and em = emf.createEntityManager(), and then query the results, I get this stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/eyJ1Akey